# Solr Memory Usage - How to reduce memory footprint for solr

Tags: solr

Q - I am forced to set Java Xmx as high as 3.5g for my solr app.. If i keep this low, my CPU hits 100% and response time for indexing increases a lot.. And i have hit OOM Error as well when this value is low..

Is this too high? If so, can I reduce this?

**Machine Details**
4 G RAM, SSD

**Solr App Details** (Standalone solr app, no shards)

1. num. of Solr Cores  = 5
2. Index Size - 2 g
3. num. of Search Hits per sec - 10 [**IMP** - All search queries have faceting..]
4. num. of times Re-Indexing per hour per core - 10 (it may happen at
   the same time at a moment for all the 5  cores)
5. Query Result Cache, Document cache and Filter Cache are all default size - 4 kb.

**top** stats -

```
  VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM
6446600 3.478g  18308 S 11.3 94.6
```

**iotop** stats

```
 DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO> 
0-1200 K/s    0-100 K/s  0          0-5%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either increasing the RAM size or increasing the frequency of Index Rebuilt. If you are rebuilding the index 10 times in an hours, then Solr may not be the right choice. Solr Index tries to give faster results by keeping the index files in the OS memory.

[Solr always use more than 90% of physical memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149296/solr-always-use-more-than-90-of-physical-memory)